# Unable to execute a selenium script through main

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, browser-automation

I am unable to execute a selenium script through main. 
I have created a executable jar of the script, it is running fine with command prompt but not with main or GET service.

I am using command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/abc.jar");
```

Also tried this:

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe" , "/c" , "Start" , "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/abc.jar"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

With both commands selenium script are not executing but other executable jar are working fine.

I need to run the script through GET Api.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: No I am not facing any error . Even code I have written after the calling of script its been executed but selenium script is not executed .

Comment: Please, could you tell us how did you create the jar file?

Comment: It worked . There was some issue with my Jar it was conflicted with libraries which I was using in my project. Thanks for your suggestion @Rcordoval

Comment: Perhaps you could share the answer (steps you follow to solve the problem), it may help future readers :)